# C# syncing two lists that are accessed by two different threads

Tags: c#, list, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I have a list of objects in a game that may or may not run complex collision testing each multiple times per second.

Because this collision testing is quite expensive each object has a list of precomputed potential collision candidates. This list gets cleared and re-populated at the beginning of  each simulation step. An object A is a potential candidate for object B, when A's and B's spherical hitboxes (which surround the actual hitboxes) intersect.

This pre-computation of the potential collision candidates list currently is done on the same thread, but I want to move it to a different thread.
For a small number of objects this already works fine, but the more objects I create, the more often each object's candidate list somehow is always empty.

This is what the two threads are doing:

**Thread #1:**

- loop through all objects and call their Update() method.

  - In this update method, the objects each run GetIntersections() which loops through the list of potential collision candidates and performs the real collision detection

**Thread #2:**

- sweep and prune algorithm that loops through all objects and:

  - clears their candidates list
  - populates the object's candidates list

Thread #1 runs more often per second than thread #2 (this is intended behaviour).

I use lock(...){ } whenever one of the threads has write access to any candidate list. But somehow each object's candidate list is empty more often the more objects I add to the scene. This results in many objects not colliding with anything anymore because their candidate lists are often empty when they should have at least one object in it.

How can I sync this correctly?

Comment: Is it a `List<T>`? Locking when writing to it is not enough; if you have foreach of the list and another thread adds or remove an element during the iteration, then you will get an exception.

Comment: Yes, it is a List<T> and I got exceptions first. But as soon as I added lock(){}, the exceptions did not occur anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use lock(...){ } whenever one of the threads has write access to any candidate list.

It is not enough to lock a list when writing. This will not prevent concurrent reading and writing, and that is not save. You need to lock the list at *every* access to the list if you are doing any writing at all. You could potentially use a [readWriteLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-8.0), to allow for concurrent reads. But I'm not sure locking is ideal for a high performance scenario like a game.

But I would propose to instead switch out the entire list. I.e.

1. At the start of the Thread #2 loop it creates a dictionary (or other type of collection that maps game objects to candidate lists).
2. As it does its computing it updates this dictionary with the candidate lists, never modifying the actual game object.
3. After it has processed all objects, it publishes the dictionary by setting a public property. Effectively "freezing" the dictionary.
4. Thread #1 copies this public property to a local variable at the start of its loop.
5. Thread #1 can use the lists in this dictionary to get the candidate lists.

Now there should be no risk that any dictionary is ever written and read to concurrently, and there is only a single synchronization point between the threads. You can also create some mechanism to reuse collections if you want to avoid the associated allocations.

Note that writing or reading a reference is atomic, but may still suffer from re-ordering issues. Using memory barriers should avoid this, or something that issues memory barriers automatically, like Interlocked.Exchange, or `lock`.

You may also want to use some similar approach to ensure Thread #2 sees a consistent view of all the object locations. You probably want to avoid cases where Thread #2 gets the position for object A at frame N, but the position for object B at frame N+1. You should probably in general try to keep as much data as possible local to a specific thread, and only have threads exchange data at specific, synchronized points.

Comment: That indeed sounds very promising. I already accounted for the frame inaccuracy you mentioned (reading frame N for object A and frame N+1 for object B) by adding a safety area around each object. This area big enough to cover the movement that the fastest object of a scene (like a bullet) would make in 1/10th of a second. Yes, this will cause some false-positives so that the real collision detection might traverses some objects that would not need it (yet) but that’s ok for me. Will try your approach tomorrow or Monday — thank you so so much!

Comment: Tried it out today and it works perfectly! The complex collision detection cycle on the main thread went down from 5ms to 1ms for 1000 test objects. Sweet! Thanks again!